# Virtuemart - Add additional description fields to products

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I'm having issue finding a bang on solution for this. I'm pretty sure I've narrowed down to what files need to be modified and somewhat what it is that needs to be added to make this happen. I'm clearly missing something.

Answer (score 1):

According to the VM developers, if you need extra fields for products, you use product types to make that happen. This allows you to add custom fields without hacking any files.

http://virtuemart.net/documentation/User_Manual/Product_Types.html#N20E96

Comment: Thanks Brent, this does help me a great deal. I need several fields, one ideally being a wysiwyg. I think making this happen will require some hacking of the core admin files. Any experience with anything like this?

Comment: As a rule I try to avoid core hacks anywhere possible, but this is not an uncommon hack. You can find specific instructions on how to implement a WYSIWYG field here - http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_editor_in_a_component